# Null value in v-model

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue

I have a Nativescript-Vue app where I make a REST call to return a response to be displayed.  It may not always be fully populated, and when that happens I get an error such as:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: null is not an object
>   (evaluating '_vm.office.address.addressLine1')"

Here is the REST response I get from the server:

```
{
   "officeId":2,
   "name":null,
   "beginDate":[
      2020,
      4,
      18
   ],
   "endDate":null,
   "officeType":null,
   "address":null
}
```

And here is the Vue code that has problems:

```
<StackLayout class="nt-input">
   <Label text="Address Line 1" class="m-b-5"/>
   <TextField :editable="!isViewOnly" v-model="office.address.addressLine1"  v-shadow="2" hint="Enter address line 1" class="-border"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Because the address hasn't been established, it will be null for new records.  Is there any way to get this to render so users can populate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `office.address` is null, then accessing `office.address.addressLine1` will always result in that error. You have to ensure that `address` is not null before doing so.

After fetching the data, you can check if `address` is null and then setting it to a new empty address object that you need:

```js
// Make the request
const office = await fetchOffice()

// Ensure that address is defined
if (!office.address) {
  office.address = {
    addressLine1: ''
  }
}

// Now that we have defined all properties on the object, we
// can assign it to the component instance to make it reactive
this.office = office
```

It is important you define any new properties on the object *before* you assign it to the component otherwise Vue won't make the new properties reactive (read [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)).

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there was a default way of displaying the fields and them being creating when used.  This is working as I need it though.