# Make value dynamic with an if - Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In my child Component (Form.vue) is being used in different Parent components (A modal.vue and General.vue). In Modal.vue I don't have the access of `information` as I don't need it. In General.vue I use the object information which is usable through props.

My question: Can I do this differently? I now use template with nearly the same code to make sure in Modal.vue the form will still work as it will get a error if I don't use the v-if.

The following code is excecuted:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group row" v-for="field in JSON.parse(processingData.fields)" :key="field.label">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div v-if="field.type == 'text'" :class="'col-' + field.cols">
                    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>

                    <template v-if="information">
                        <input
                            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                            type="text"
                            :ref="field.field"
                            @input="getS(field.field, $event.target.value)"
                            v-model="information[field.field]"
                            value=""
                        />
                    </template>

                    <template v-if="!information">
                        <input
                            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                            type="text"
                            :ref="field.field"
                            @input="getS(field.field, $event.target.value)"
                        />
                    </template>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I usually create a `form` object and you can then just use `v-model="form.information"` since `form` should always be defined as an object. An undefined `form.information` will then not throw an error. I do not know what your data pattern looks like and why you are using `information[field.field]`

Comment: @Flame I updated my post. So you have all the code. Then you can answer your own question. Hopefully you can help me further after this.

Comment: You also assume that `information[field.field]` always exists. What happens if that breaks? If you make sure `information` is always defined you can get rid of the `v-if` - I think that is the parent component's problem. How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61298603/null-value-in-v-model